# google app engine and php runtime environment

Tags: php, google-app-engine

In google app engine, the PHP runtime for App Engine is an Experimental feature in Limited Preview. However for a limited period, only whitelisted applications may be deployed on App Engine if they use the PHP runtime.

Does anyone has an idea what does the above statement mean? whether I will be able to host my php website on GAE or not and for how long? what are the restrictions?

Comment: Means you can only run GAE locally. They will announce when it is possible to upload/run PHP on their servers soon.

Comment: @Dave That means I wont be able to host my php website on GAE and I will have to wait for php release on GAE? I have locally setup my php website using GAE SDK and its ready to launch. Should I host it on some other web hosting provider until I get any update from google?

Comment: If your code is pure PHP, then yes, you can host it somewhere else.

Comment: @TanuGupta let me know the app-id and i'll see if I can help you out with getting the app whitelisted.

Comment: @StuartLangley, Thanks. app-id is experiencehinduism. Just one thing more I want to ask you, I want to register a website and want to host the same on google app engine. I dont want any sub-domain like .appspot.com.

I read a lot about GAE but I think I ended up with confusion.

Suppose the domain is: www.mydomain.com. Can I use google app engine without any sub-domain? And then will I be eligible for GAE free services?

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Comment: also see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/credit/google-appengine/jC_K-YlmXhM/XPJYq1HUgusJ

Answer (score 1):

You can only run PHP on GAE locally for now. You can register your app for the limited preview at https://gaeforphp.appspot.com/. That would allow you to deploy it. But please note that it is still an experimental feature, so there might be some problems.

Comment: Over 1000 apps have been whitelisted so far